# Why can we figure out the relationship between a point and a plane by a matrix's determinant?

Tags: matrices

A plane can be taken to be  a quadruple $(a, b, c, d)$. Then a point is taken to be a triple of planes $(P, Q, R)$. The point $(p, q, r)$ is valid if and only if the determinant of the matrix $A$ below is non-zero.

$$A=
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        Pa & Pb & Pc\\
        Qa & Qb & Qc\\
        Ra & Rb & Rc\\
    \end{array}
\right]
$$

We can get it by simple linear algebra: The point $(P, Q, R)$ can be presented as the equation root of $Ax = b$. If this is valid then $Ax = b$ has an unique solution which implies $\det(A) \neq 0$.

Given that the point $(P, Q, R)$ is valid, it lies behind, on, or in-front of the plane $S$ if and only if the following expression is negative, zero or positve.

$$
\left\vert
    \begin{array}{cccc}
        Pa & Pb & Pc & Pd\\
        Qa & Qb & Qc & Qd\\
        Ra & Rb & Rc & Rd\\
        Sa & Sb & Sc & Sd
    \end{array}
\right\vert

\left\vert
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        Pa & Pb & Pc\\
        Qa & Qb & Qc\\
        Ra & Rb & Rc
    \end{array}
\right\vert
$$

My question is: *What is the mechanism behind this?*

Comment: I suggest taking a course on linear algebra.

Comment: Can you specify what your first sentence means? Do you associate $(a, b, c, d)$ with the plane $ax + by + cz = d$? What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: Do you associate (a,b,c,d) with the plane ax+by+cz=d?  YES

What do you mean by "valid"? That means (P, Q, R) is the only point 
shared by 3 planes.

Comment: The Question has a type error: det(A) = 0 should be det(A) != 0

Comment: But for your matrix $A$ we always have $\det A=0$? Where did $d$ disappear?

Comment: Something doesn't add up. If you mean the plane $ax+by+cz=d$, then there is only a single plane. Not three planes. Also: define "in front of". Looking from where?

Comment: Jyrki, Ax=b has an unique solution which implies det(A)!=0. I've fixed the type error.

Let Plane P = (Pa, Pb, Pc, Pd), Then Plane Q = (Qa, Qb, Qc, Qd), and so on.

Comment: ax + by + cz = d can also be written as (a, b, c)*(x, y, z) = d. (a, b, c) is the normal vector.

Comment: Actually we can present a 3D plane by a point p(x, y, z) and a normal vector n(nx, ny, nz). 
that is (px - p)*n = 0. it's equivalent to ax + by + cz = d. 
But have more clear geometrical significance. 
if a point px on the plane, dot(px - p, n) = 0.
If px in front of it, dot(px - p, n) > 0

Answer (score 1):

The only way the question makes sense to me is that $Pa$ actually means $a_P$ instead of the product of the two numbers $P$ and $a$ as I would normally expect. IOW, the coefficient of $x$ in the equation of the plane $P$. Similarly for others. So we are given 4 planes determined by the four equations
$$
a_ix+b_iy+c_iz=d_i,
$$
where the subscript $i$ takes values from the set $\{P,Q,R,S\}$. From the problem description we know that the first three planes are aligned in such a way that they have a unique point of intersection $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Let us look at the augmented matrix
$$
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}a_P&b_P&c_P&d_P\\a_Q&b_Q&c_Q&d_Q\\a_R&b_R&c_R&d_R\end{array}\right).
$$
Let $M_j, j\in\{a,b,c,d\}$ be the determinant of the 3x3 matrix gotten from $M$ by removing the column corresponding to $j$. So $\det A$ from the OP is now equal to $M_d$, and we know that $M_d\neq0$.

Cramer's rule tells us that the point of intersection has coordinates
$$ x_0=\frac{M_a}{M_d},\quad y_0=-\frac{M_b}{M_d},\quad z_0=\frac{M_c}{M_d}.$$

Let us then compute the determinant of the 4x4 matrix
$$
N=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}a_P&b_P&c_P&d_P\\a_Q&b_Q&c_Q&d_Q\\a_R&b_R&c_R&d_R\\
a_S&b_S&c_S&d_S\end{array}\right).
$$
We expand along the bottom row and get
$$
\det N=-a_SM_a+b_SM_b-c_SM_c+d_SM_d=-a_S(x_0M_d)-b_S(y_0M_d)-c_S(z_0M_d)+d_SM_d,
$$
so
$$
\det N=-M_d(a_Sx_0+b_Sy_0+c_Sz_0-d_S).
$$
Let us write $\vec{n}=(a_S,b_S,c_S)$ for this normal of the plane $S$. Let $\vec{r}=(x_S,y_S,z_S)$ be the vector from the origin to some point $(x_S,y_S,z_S)$ on the plane $S$, so we know that $\vec{n}\cdot \vec{r}=d_S.$ Let $\vec{r}_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be the vector from the origin to the point of intersection $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Then $a_Sx_0+b_Sy_0+c_Sz_0=\vec{n}\cdot\vec{r}_0$, so our earlier equation reads
$$
\det N=-\det A (\vec{n}\cdot \vec{r_0}-\vec{n}\cdot\vec{r})=(\det A)\ \vec{n}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0).
$$

This tells us that the sign of the product $\det N \ \det A$ is the same as the sign of the dot product $\vec{n}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0)$. A geometric interpretation of this last dot produt is that it is positive/zero/negative, if the projection of the difference vector $\vec{r}-\vec{r}_0$ onto the chosen normal vector $\vec{n}$ is a positive/zero/negative multiple of $\vec{n}$. IOW, we get a plus sign, if the point of intersection $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is on the opposite side of the plane $S$ from the one pointed at by $\vec{n}$, and vice versa. Of course, the inner product equals zero, if and only if the point of intersection is on the plane $S$.

Comment: The answer is accepted. Clear presentation and excellent deduction! Thanks, Jyrki:)

Comment: @CChen No, the answer is not accepted, as you forgot to [actually accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011).